# How do we perform installation testing of a native Android app on different devices

Tags: android, mobile, installation

We have one Android app which is live as well. So far we have some device in the company (around 3-4) and we have tested the app (installation and full functionality) over them and all working fine. But there are so many crashes reported by the users along with the device and os details and we are not able to get a solution that we can cover maximum devices so at least app crash not encounter by end user.

Can some one help us in this ? or let us know the services or tools (paid or free) so at a time we can test out app on real device and get the report so we be sure and mitigate the app crashes?

Comment: [This](https://www.browserstack.com/app-live) might be what you're looking for, but I don't have any first-hand experience with them or any others like them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several apps that support testing such as:

1. SauceLabs
2. AWS Device Farm
3. Xamarin Test Cloud
4. BrowserStack
5. Perfecto mobile
6. Test Object
7. Bugsnag

[Bugsnag](http://www.bugsnag.com/platforms/android/) has modules to test mobile applications in both iOS and Android. 
 Plus it specializes in crash reporting, which may make your troubleshooting easier. SauceLabs or AWS Device Farm is cost effective solutions. Appium has integration with Test Object to spy the objects for the app under test.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look for *Appium clouds*, for example

- Xamarin Test Cloud: https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud
- Bitbar Cloud: https://bitbar.com/testing/

... and you can find some others on google.

or some platform was owned by Compuware, former Adlex company, later Dynatrace company, called **KeyNote**, not sure if it still works. This was more oriented on response time measurement from various part of the world.

Then you can try to install your app on thousands of real devices and see, how this succeed. Just count with it, that this is not a cheap solution.